# Creating a C++ style class for storing a data on 2D grid on GPU memory

Tags: c++, classes, cuda

**UPDATED**

I would like to create a class, which is intended to represent a field of values on a **2D** grid. So, I would like to access the elements with a double square bracket `A[i][j]`, and inside the `__global__` or `__device__` function access the dimensions of the field - `nx_, ny_`, because I do not want to pass them each time as an arguments to the functions.
In order to execute multiple threads on this structure, as far as I understand, I have to pass it as a pointer on the device memory. I've come with a following solution, but it doesn't look very beatufil and efficient.

```
template <typename T>
struct Field
{
    DEVHOST Field(size_t nx, size_t ny)
    {
        cudaMalloc(reinterpret_cast<void**>(&dev_ptr_), sizeof(dev_ptr_));
        init_kernel<<<1,1>>>(dev_ptr_, nx, ny); 
    }

    DEVHOST ~Field()
    {
        delete_kernel<<<1,1>>>(dev_ptr_);
        cudaFree(dev_ptr_);
    }

    Field<T>* devPtr()
    {
         return dev_ptr_;
    }

    const Field<T>* devPtr() const
    {
         return dev_ptr_;
    }

    DEVHOST size_t size() const
    {
        return nx_ * ny_;
    }

    DEVHOST T* operator[](size_t idx)
    {
        return data_ + idx * nx_;
    }

    DEVHOST const T* operator[](size_t idx) const
    {
        return data_ + idx * nx_;
    }

public:
    size_t nx_;
    size_t ny_;

    T* data_;

    Field<T>* dev_ptr_;
};

template <typename T>
KERNEL void init_kernel(Field<T>* f, size_t nx, size_t ny)
{
    f->nx_ = nx;
    f->ny_ = ny;
    f->data_ = reinterpret_cast<T*>(malloc(nx * ny * sizeof(T)));
}

template <typename T>
KERNEL void delete_kernel(Field<T>* f)
{
    free(f->data_);
}
```

In order to create an instance of `Field<T>` to be worked with further, I need to call a kernel, which initializes it. And then a kernel to delete this object on the device memory. The code on the host will look like:

```
Field<float>* f;
init_kernel<<<1,1>>>(f, 100, 100);
delete_kernel<<<1,1>>>(f);
```

What would be the more robust and clever way to implement the desired functionality. I would appreciate any suggestions, or references to the good practices of `CUDA` Programming, except for the `docs.nvidia.com`.

**The intended usage**

Several instances of this `Field` are stored in another structure, namely

```
struct NavierStokesSolver{
    //some methods
private:
    //velocity fields
    Field<Vec2> v_old, v_new;

    //pressure fields
    Field<float> p_old, p_new;

    //color fields
    Field<Color3> c_old, c_new;
};
```

There is a method, which runs an iteration on the data, where the `device` pointers are passed to the `__global__` functions, and updated.
Something like

```
 advect_kernel<<<blocks, threads>>>(v_new.devPtr(), v_old.devPtr(), c_new.devPtr(), c_old.devPtr(), decay, dt);
 project_kernel<<<blocks, threads>>>(v_old.devPtr(), p_old.devPtr());
```

Comment: Why do you think this is not efficient?

Comment: @G.Sliepen I have a little experience with `CUDA`, but calling a kernel object to allocate a lot of memory using only one thread seems to be a waste of resources. Another point, is that for object, which is intended to store two-dimensional data - there are some special features with `CUDA` memory allocation - there is a notion of *Pitched* memory, which may be relevant in that case.

Comment: Ok the obvious solution to the first is to not allocate using a kernel object, but allocate it outside it, and just pass a pointer to the allocated memory to your kernel functions. And yes, you can allocate pitched memory (see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1047369/allocate-2d-array-on-device-memory-in-cuda)). I would make it so your `class Field` doesn't allocate memory itself, but you give its constructor a pointer to the memory allocated using `cudaMallocPitch()`, as well as the pitch, and make `operator[]` take the pitch into account.

Comment: @G.Sliepen thanks! It is really helpful!

Comment: To be backwards compatible with C all fields including pointers to functions are public, there is no reason to use the public keyword here.

Comment: Do you have a unit test for the struct that demonstrates how it is used in real code?

Comment: @pacmaninbw concerning the unit tests - I do not have them (I know, that is at least a very good practice, to have a unit test for crucial parts of the program, but haven't come with an idea for a good structure of them). I've made a slight modificiation, which solves part of the mentioned problem - need to explicitly call kernel for allocation and deallocation (now they are called in the constructor and destructor). I have updated the post.

Comment: @pacmaninbw `public` keyword is really uncessary, I've left it, because initially intended to make these fields `private`